# Array initialization giving error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am having trouble with following fragment of my code giving error:

```
solution.c:1:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
 ^
solution.c:2:1: error: initializer element is not constant
 int *min=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
```

Here is my code fragment:

```
int *arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
int *min=malloc(sizeof(int)*100000);
int top1;

void init() {
    memset(arr,-1,sizeof(arr));
    memset(min,-1,sizeof(min));
    top1=-1;
}
```

what's going wrong?

NOTE: This `init()` function would be called for every test case, so I am clearing memory and `arr, min, top1` are global

Comment: Nitpick: `memset(arr,-1,sizeof(arr));` will set only `4` bytes to `-1`.

Comment: but error is popping up at initial 2 lines itself?

Comment: @kaylum: I checked that, but couldn't help

Comment: Why not? Both the linked question and even the error message itself tells you the exact problem. Initializers for variables with static duration must be constant expression - ie, known at compile time. A `malloc` call is not a constant expression.

Comment: so what should be the fix, can you plz elaborate?

Comment: Change to `int arr[100000];`. Or leave as `int *arr;` and then have `init` do the `malloc`.

Comment: Also `sizeof(arr)` does not work because `arr` is not actually a C array. `sizeof(arr)` will only give you `sizeof(int *)` which is always going to be 4 or 8.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. It helped!!